Do people in Sydney or even Australia say napkin, tissue, or serviette?
When I first moved to Australia (Sydney to be precise), I used napkin as a force of habit. However, I ended up switching to tissues. However, online, I read that serviette is a French-sounding synonym that people claim is being used in Australia, New Zealand, Canada, Ireland, and United Kingdom. However, in Sydney, I had seen this word used only once, and it was written like this "Serviettes (Tissues)" on a sign.
People normally would say "cutlery", though this would refer to just the forks, knives, and spoons, which are sometimes grouped with the napkin.
Peppa Pig, which is set in England, uses the term "napkin", and Peppa Pig overdoes it with the England terms, and never uses any Americanisms, except for one episode in which they holiday in America, and a rabbit said "gas", which is the American word for "petrol".
I have yet to hear what they say in Bluey. I watched another Australian show called Bureau of Magical Things, and I haven’t heard any of these terms used in any of the episodes.
Serviette is an extra syllable and much longer to say than "napkin" or "tissue".

I can't find any evidence online that Australians call table napkins 'tissues'. Are you sure the sign didn't just mean that they were paper napkins? Both terms are used in the UK - see this explanation.

It is rude of you to say that Peppa Pig 'overdoes it with the England terms', given that she is English.

It would be like saying that Pinocchio overdoes it with a Tuscany accent.

@Kate So which is correct? Napkin or tissue? I read people on Reddit say napkin is an American-exclusive word. I never heard anyone in Australia say “serviette”.

serviette is French for napkin. As for Peppa Pig she is English so why are you even using that as an example for anything other than British English? And tissues in Australia are what in the US we call tissues or Kleenex. [There's also tissue paper of course]

I watch every single TV series/show I can find from Australia on popular streaming sites. One can learn tons of stuff from these shows, including things like "How you going?" for How you doing? or journo for journalist. And most interesting: lounger for living/sitting room. For a true laugh, see: Daniel MacDonald in Unbelievable or Mystery Road, with an indigenous detective. Really great.

Megas - I'm not Australian, but since I told you I couldn't find any evidence that the term was used in Australia for a table napkin, why are you still asking me if it is correct? (When I said 'both terms are used in the UK', I meant serviette and napkin.)

@KateBunting - my (UK) paternal grandmother said 'napkin' and my mother 'serviette' about the same things. Some people say there is a class distinction, with 'napkin' being middle/upper. This figures. Grandma's napkins sat on the table in 'napkin rings' made of silver.

@Megas Note that in French serviette has only two syllables /sɛʁ.vjɛt/ and that its British pronunciation comes close.

In French, I could see them pronouncing it as “ser-way”, but in English, wouldn’t they say it as “ser-we-at”?

@Lambie Americans sometimes ask “how is it going?”, which can also mean “how is it doing?”, but they never ask “how you going?” Weird, but I think Americans can understand this means “how you doing?” unless you are talking about travel.

There is no 'w' sound in serviette in either language. English SER-VEE-ETT, French SAIR-VYET.

@Megas Here is a UK pronunciation and here is a French one.

People in USA sometimes call sitting rooms a “lounge”, but that is only if they are big with sofas. Never heard lounger. A living room is called a lounge if you are in a public place as living rooms are only used for a home.

I am saying that Australians say: How you going? for How are you?. The pronuniciation in English is: sir-vee-et. Both in BrE and AmE. Though Americans posh or not don't use that term.  No, Americans do not call a living room in a house a lounge. Australians do.

Yes, I never said Americans call a living room at a house a lounge. However, a lounge is like a living room in public. Yes, Australians say "How you going" for "How are you?", but it is informal, so "How are you?" is the common one.

The very simple distinction in Melbourne anyway is that “serviette” refers to a paper napkin while “napkin” usually suggests a piece of fabric. A paper napkin is not the same as a tissue either, as it is usually textured and thicker, and folded into thirds or similar. I would ask for a napkin unless it's at a restaurant, sausage stall, cafe or some place where they obviously only have serviettes.

british-english
Napkin and Serviette are one of the classic examples of U and non-U speech, as categorised in the 1950s, the hypothesis being that members of middle classes would adopt new terms like "toilet", "sweet"(to describe a dessert) or "serviette", whereas the genuine upper classes would use older words "lavatory", "pudding", and "napkin". The distinction still exists, though the particular differences have changed.
For the non-native speaker of English.  Ignore the above. The words napkin and serviette mean the same.  There may be some subtle class distinctions, but as you are non-native speakers of English, you are not part of the British class system, so you can safely ignore it.

While the question was about usage in Sydney, this is about British usage, and is included for comparison.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U_and_non-U_English I had to check the meanings of U and non-U, I heard it a few times, years ago, so I should know but couldn't remember what they stood for. Maybe I'm not the only one?

@Mari-LouA thanks for linking to that.  It's rather dated now, but the idea that "middle classes try to signal that they are not lower classes by language, but upper class don't need to, so use more plain language"

I am from Sydney, Australia. In a cafe, I would probably ask for a serviette. To me a tissue refers to something different (like the tissues in a tissue box) than a serviette, but if you asked for a tissue they would know what you mean. Don't think anybody really uses napkin - napkin sounds very American to me.
